# Watch app - can't see simulators under active schemes

Tags: xcode, watchos

I've created a Watch App in XCode, blank app, can't see the scheme to launch watch simulator.

I've also looked into settings under build/Architecture etc. and changed them from iOS to watchOS but still unable to get it working.

The question, how to make this test project run in a watch simulator. (screenshot 1)

on a side note, under WatchFramework I do see simulators. (screenshot 2)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen sometimes when switching between Xcode betas.

Have a look under **Build Settings** and **Deployment** for the Watch App Target and make sure the correct version of watchOS is selected.

Also double check SWIFT_VERSION and TARGET_DEVICE at the bottom under **User-Defined**